# How to rename a sellable item in Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog

Is there any way to rename a sellable item in Commerce?
I see that the Display Name can be changed, but don't see any way to modify the name?

Is there some reason for this being disallowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sellable item in Sitecore Commerce is an entity stored in the `CatalogEntities` table in the `SharedEnvironments` database. The name of the sellable item is the `Id` of the entity (ie. `Entity-SellableItem-XXXXXX`). The `Id` is a primary key on the `CatalogEntities` table and I believe it is protected for this reason.

For a normal Sitecore item, the ID of an item and its name are two separate properties (stored in two separate fields in the `Items` table on the Master or Web database). For a Commerce Sellable Entity there is no distinction of these two properties in the database layer.